# Adición de texto en javascript

Tags: javascript

*Hola, intentando no logro hacer lo siguiente:*

Ingresar por teclado un texto y luego guardarlo en una variable , supongamos que la persona ingresa esto: '{soy alto} Pepito998'

entonces:

```
var nombre = '{soy alto} Pepito998';
```

Ahora lo que necesito es añadir algo a lo que está entre {} ,sin reemplazar las llaves y sin borrar lo que está dentro, como le hago? osea que quedara como: `'{soy alto dev} Pepito998'` ,(en este caso agregé la palabra `'dev'` dentro de las llaves,  alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿Y cómo es que escribiste esto: `(soy alto) Pepito998` y aparece esto en la variable: `{soy alto} Pepito998` ? ¿`(...)` cambiados por `{...}`?

Comment: Me equivoqué lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este código de muestra, se usa el caracter especial arroba (**@**) para usarlo en la concatenación del texto:

Básicamente lo que hago es:

- Recibir el valor del campo input.
- Utilizo la función *`replace`* para reemplazar el caracter especial con el texto del input.
- Muestro el resultado.

Para continuar con la concatenación de texto, es necesario que el resultado devuelva el caracter especial utilizado.

Este es solo un ejemplo *(y desconozco si es la mejor manera)*, pero creo que puedes ir mirando por aquí si te sirve.

```js
var nombre = '{soy alto @} Pepito998';

function agregarTexto(texto) {

  var caracter_especial = "@";

  nombre = nombre.replace(caracter_especial, texto) + ' ' + caracter_especial;

  document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = nombre;

}
```

```html
Valor inicial de la variable:
<span id="valorVariable">{soy alto @} Pepito998</span>
<br/>
<br/> Ingrese texto:
<input type="text" maxlength="10" id="txt" />
<br/>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="agregarTexto(document.getElementById('txt').value);" /> Resultado:
<span id="resultado">{soy alto @} Pepito998</span>
```

Comment: Funciona bien la 1ª vez, pero luego no. De todos modos el OP debe decir el **patrón**, o sea, si lo que quiere es que todo lo insertado vaya antes de la llave de cierre `}`. Si es eso, será muy fácil adaptar el ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias me ha funcionado :)

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con lo sgte.

```js
var nombre = '{soy alto} Pepito998';
var textoAInsertar = ' dev'; // Notese que hay un espacio delante de dev
var indice = nombre.indexOf('}'); // El texto se insertará antes de este caracter
nombre = nombre.substring(0, indice) + textoAInsertar + nombre.substr(indice); //Reemplazando el nombre original

//Solo para mostrar el resultado. No lo incluyas en tu código
document.write(nombre);
```